# Set Binding of Element inside Datatemplate

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datatemplate

I am building a DataGrid with DataGridTemplateColumns. The CellTemplate is created as DataTemplate in XAML:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="StringCell">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Path=Cells.Values[3]}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=AttributeValue.ObjectValue, Mode=OneWay}"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

This is actually working, but I want to set the DataContext of the Grid in code when creating the Column. I tried this:

```
DataTemplate dt = cellTemplates["StringCell"] as DataTemplate;
(dt.LoadContent() as Grid).SetBinding(DataContextProperty, new Binding("Cells.Values[3]") { Mode = BindingMode.OneWay });

DataGridTemplateColumn dataGridTemplateColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn()
{
    CellTemplate = dt
};
```

but it's not working because LoadContent creates a new instance and doesn't change the template. Is there a way to set the DataContext in code?

Comment: Please explain why you want to set the Grid's DataContext at all. This is not what you typically do inside DataTemplates.

Comment: I have a pretty complex data structure that is used as ItemSource and I have to pass an index to the Binding. So its acutally: `Cells.Values[ i ]`. The alternative would be to create the Datatemplate completely in code, but I would prefer to have it in XAML

Answer (score 1):

Rather than modifying an existing template (which is not always possible), it's easier to create a new one from a string.

You didn't show the implementation of the classes used, so I'll show an example for such a class structure:

```cs
namespace Core2022.SO.ottoKranz
{
    public class SomeClass
    {
        public SomeItem[]? Cells { get; set; }
    }

    public class SomeItem
    {
        public AttributeClass? AttributeValue { get; set; }
    }

    public class AttributeClass
    {
        public object? ObjectValue { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here is an example of creating a data template:

```cs
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace Core2022.SO.ottoKranz
{
    public class CodeBehind
    {
        const string DataTemplateString = @"
<DataTemplate xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'
              xmlns:local='clr-namespace:Core2022.SO.ottoKranz'
              DataType='local:SomeClass'>
    <Grid DataContext='{{Binding Path=Cells.Values[{0}]}}'>
        <TextBlock Text='{{Binding Path=AttributeValue.ObjectValue, Mode=OneWay}}'
                   TextWrapping='Wrap'/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>";
        public static void OnGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
        {
            int index = 3;

            string templateString =string.Format(DataTemplateString, index);

            DataTemplate template = (DataTemplate) XamlReader.Parse(templateString);

            DataGridTemplateColumn dataGridTemplateColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn()
            {
                CellTemplate = template
            };

            e.Column = dataGridTemplateColumn;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143024/in-wpf-how-to-change-a-datatemplates-textblocks-text-binding-in-code):

```
private DataTemplate GeneratePropertyBoundTemplate(int i, string templateKey)
{
    DataTemplate cellTemplate = cellTemplates[templateKey] as DataTemplate; //Load DataTemplate from Resource 
    FrameworkElementFactory factory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ContentPresenter)); 
    factory.SetValue(ContentPresenter.ContentTemplateProperty, cellTemplate);
    factory.SetBinding(ContentPresenter.ContentProperty, new Binding("Cells.Values[" + i + "]")); 
    return new DataTemplate { VisualTree = factory }; 
}
```

You just wrap the DataTemplate in a ContentPresenter and set his Binding.