# XamlReader dynamic event in DataTemplate

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

Want to add click event to the button in datatemplate.
Have some code:

```
 var temp = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(
                   new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(
                       @"<DataTemplate xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'><Button><TextBlock Text='1' TextAlignment='Center'/></Button></DataTemplate>"
                   )));
 var button = temp.LoadContent() as Button;
 button.Click += (sender, args) =>
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("123");
                    };
 return temp;
```

So, when i click at the button, nothing happens.
What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381740/changing-datatemplate-textblock-property-at-runtime) question, it's quite similar. To get what you need you can use Framework Element Factory like this:

```
private DataTemplate CreateTemplate()
    {
        FrameworkElementFactory fef = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Button));//new FrameworkElementFactory("<Button Name='ButtonName'><TextBlock Text='1' TextAlignment='Center'/></Button>");
        fef.AddHandler(Button.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(b_Click));
        fef.SetValue(Button.ContentProperty, "1");

        return new DataTemplate() { VisualTree = fef };
    }

    private void b_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("123");
    }
```